# Finding fields Elasticsearch has matched on

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch to search for a group a user should join. I have the user data nested into the search query. On return I get back the closest matched group that user should be in.

The field I am searching on is a nested field as follows:

```
`{"interests": [
                {"topics":["python", "stackoverflow", "elasticsearch"]}, 
                {"topics":["arts", "textiles"]}
               ]}`
```

However if you want an understanding of a match - how do you do this?

Elasticsearch does have an explain function which says what the scoring is made up of using tfidf, but not specifically what terms were used.

For example, if I search for 'Textile', the doc should match on 'textiles'. Thus I want the term 'textiles' to be returned in explain or some other way.

The only way I see that provides this need, is to store the search and the document retrieved and then process both to discover words ES has most likely matched on.

EDIT - for some more clarity of the question

An example in my index of a group which has `"interests": ['arts', 'fine arts', 'art painting', 'arts and crafts', 'sports']`

Now my search, I am looking for `Arts` and many other things. Now the term I am searching for comes up in this list many times, thus should always be a contributor.

What I want in the response is to say these words were matched `['arts', 'fine arts', 'art painting', 'arts and crafts']`along with the degree to which they match i..e 'arts' should be higher than the others, but all others are also relevant

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch allows you to specify the `_name` field for all queries and
filters. This means that you can separate your query into different parts with
separate names, which will allow you to determine which parts matched.

For example:

```
{
  "query" : {
      "bool" : {
          "should" : [
              {"match" : { "interests.topics" : {"query" : "python", "_name" : "py-topic"} }},
              {"match" : { "interests.topics" : {"query" : "arts", "_name" : "arts-topic"} }}
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

Then, in your response, you will get back any array of which queries (or
filters) matched and you can determine if the `py-topic` query and/or the
`arts-topic` query matched above.

Comment: thanks lee - do you know if this works with nested queries? Am just trying it out on mine and no luck so far

Comment: @redrubia it should work with nested queries, if you want to edit the issue to include your mapping I can try to give a full example.